# load query every second using node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I want to select data after inserting, so what i want is to check it every second if there is a new data. I create a select query then try to display it using console log. Please help me, I'm a newbie. Here is my code

Controller

```
var connection = require('../../config/db');

function myQuery(callback) {
this.pushActivity = function(req, res, next) {
    var salesman_id = req.query.salesman_id
    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
        con.query('SELECT * FROM `activities` where salesman_id="'+salesman_id+'" and kunci="0" and created=NOW()', function(err, data) {
            con.release();
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ status: 400, message: 'Failed', result: [] });
            } else {
                console.log(data)
                // return res.json(data);
            }
        });
    });
};
callback();
}

function wait10sec(){
 setTimeout(function(){
     myQuery(wait10sec);
 }, 10000);
}

myQuery(wait10sec);

module.exports = new myQuery();
```

Router

```
var ad = 
require('./../../controllers/mobile/activity_after_deal');

module.exports = {
   configure: function(app) {
      app.route('/api_ad_push_notif').get(ad.pushActivity);
   }
};
```

Comment: please try to explain your idea clearly. where is the client? where is the server?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good and efficient approach .Instead of using this ,try to use listener on put request which changes the data and after change event,execute the Get query and output the changed data.Use  [Socket.io Library](https://socket.io/) for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use socket.io .
by this module you can send live event to server and get response.

for example when send new data, you can select query or send emit to user or show it on console log

Answer (score 0):

You can create worker by adding

```
setInterval(function(){        
  //run query and console        
}, 1000) and you can set time
```

Comment: Hi Mudassir, please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It's important to follow StackOverflow standards.